# Qt Quick iOS: How to keep audio playing while app is in background

Tags: ios, qt, qml, qt-quick

I’m developing a `WebRadio` application in `qml` for `iOS` devices with `Qt 5.2`. To play the audio stream I use the `MediaPlayer` type which works fine.

However, in `iOS`, when I switch to another application or go back to home (in other words when the app go to background) the sound stops, but I want it to continue playing.

I know how to do it in `objective-C` by activating the `AVAudioSession` and add the audio background mode the `info.plist` file.

But I really don't know how to do it in `qml`.

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the audio background mode to the info.plist file or via the capabilities tab in Xcode.